# disable user hover and click for CSS rating

Tags: css, rating

I have the below rating CSS code but I want to disable any change for a pre-loaded stars.
anybody have any ideas how to disable mouse hover over and click?. thanks.
..................................

```
  <style>
        /****** Rating Starts *****/
        @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

        fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body{ margin: 20px; }
        h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

        .rating { 
            border: none;
          //  float: left;
            float: right;
            //position: absolute;
        }

        .rating > input { display: none; } 


        .rating > label:before { 
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
        //    display: inline-block;
            content: "\f005";
        }

        .rating > .half:before { 
            content: "\f089";
            position: absolute;
        }

        .rating > label { 
            color: #ddd; 
            float: right; 
            //position: absolute;
        }


        .rating > input:checked ~ label, 
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,  
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  }

        .rating > input:checked + label:hover, 
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
        .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }     


    </style>
```